# Opinion - Python: Multiple Inheritance or Composition

Tags: python, inheritance

I am currently re-designing some objects in Python related to a crypto-currency project.  In my design I have favored the use of composition and dependency injection wherever it makes sense.

A `transaction` object is a data structure with fields that get split and joined together to and from a string (serialization/de-serialization).  In the world of crypto, there are variations of this data structure where fields may be added, removed, or serialized in a different order.

I have the basic `transaction` class:

```
class CTransaction(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Basics
        self.nVersion = 1
        self.vin = []
        self.vout = []
        self.nLockTime = 0
        self.sha256 = None

    def deserialize(self, f):
        self.nVersion = struct.unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        self.vin = deser_vector(f, CTxIn)
        self.vout = deser_vector(f, CTxOut)
        self.nLockTime = struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0]
        self.sha256 = None

    def serialize(self):
        r = ""
        r += struct.pack("<i", self.nVersion)
        r += ser_vector(self.vin)
        r += ser_vector(self.vout)
        r += struct.pack("<I", self.nLockTime)
        return r
```

A variation of this could be a transaction that supports messages.  I use inheritance and add in the additional message field.  It just gets appended to the end during serialization:

```
class CTransactionMessage(CTransaction):
    def __init__(self, Tx_Message):
        super(CTransactionMessage, self).__init__()
        # Support for Transaction message is version 2
        self.nVersion = 2
        self.strTxComment = Tx_Message

    def deserialize(self, f):
        super(CTransactionMessage, self).deserialize(f)
        self.strTxComment = deser_string(f)

    def serialize(self):
        r = super(CTransactionMessage, self).serialize()
        r += ser_string(self.strTxComment)
        return r
```

In a another variation you have could have a transaction for POS type currencies.

```
class CPosTransaction(CTransaction):
    def __init__(self, ntime):
        super(CPosTransaction, self).__init__()
        # POS blocks have an 'nTime' field
        self.nTime = ntime

    def deserialize(self, f):
        self.nVersion = struct.unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        self.nTime = struct.unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        self.vin = deser_vector(f, CTxIn)
        self.vout = deser_vector(f, CTxOut)
        self.nLockTime = struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0]
        self.sha256 = None

    def serialize(self):
        r = ""
        r += struct.pack("<i", self.nVersion)
        r += struct.pack("<i", self.nTime)
        r += ser_vector(self.vin)
        r += ser_vector(self.vout)
        r += struct.pack("<I", self.nLockTime)
        return r
```

In the POS case the serialize/deserialize methods had to be redefined since the new field is added somewhere in the middle.

Finally, there is a variation where you can have a transaction for POS type currencies that support messages.

I could duplicate a lot of code and write a new class as such:

```
class CPosTransactionMessage(CTransaction):
    def __init__(self, Tx_Message, ntime):
        super(CPosTransactionMessage, self).__init__()
        # Support for Transaction message is version 2
        self.nVersion = 2
        self.strTxComment = Tx_Message
        # POS blocks have an 'nTime' field
        self.nTime = ntime

    def deserialize(self, f):
        self.nVersion = struct.unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        self.nTime = struct.unpack("<i", f.read(4))[0]
        self.vin = deser_vector(f, CTxIn)
        self.vout = deser_vector(f, CTxOut)
        self.nLockTime = struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0]
        self.sha256 = None
        self.strTxComment = deser_string(f)

    def serialize(self):
        r = ""
        r += struct.pack("<i", self.nVersion)
        r += struct.pack("<i", self.nTime)
        r += ser_vector(self.vin)
        r += ser_vector(self.vout)
        r += struct.pack("<I", self.nLockTime)
        r += ser_string(self.strTxComment)
        return r
```

Or I could use multiple inheritance.  (Note: I am not sure if I am doing this correctly)

```
class CPosTransactionMessage(CPosTransaction, CTransactionMessage):
    def __init__(self, Tx_Message, ntime):
        CPosTransaction.__init__(self, ntime)
        CTransactionMessage.__init__(self, Tx_Message)

    def deserialize(self, f):
        CPosTransaction.deserialize(self, f)
        CTransactionMessage.deserialize(self, f)

    def serialize(self):
        r = CPosTransaction.serialize(self)
        r += CTransactionMessage.serialize(self)
        return r
```

Should I instead use composition and separate the serialize/deserialize methods into more objects? Or am I over thinking/over complicating this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `super` is your friend, especially if you are doing diamond-shaped inheritance.

Secondly: consider not doing that. Python supports it, but it's generally a good idea to stick to mixins wherever possible.
So in your case it would be:

```
class CTransaction(object):
    def serialize(self)
        "do stuff"


class PosMixin(object):
    def serialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PosMixin, self).serialize(*args, **kwargs)
        # do my stuff

class AnotherMixin(object):
    def serialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnotherMixin, self).serialize(*args, **kwargs)
        # do some more stuff

class TransactionPos(CTransaction, PosMixin): pass

class TransactionAnotherPos(CTransaction, PosMixin, AnotherMixin): pass
```

Another way would be to register callbacks manually and then invoke them. That's your dependency injection. But unless you generate a lot of variation of these classes on-the-fly, there's little point.

Answer (score 0):

If the serialization format is free and not strictly dependent on the data structure (in your example `TxMessage` is appended at the end, while `nTime` is inserted in the middle) what you can do is using a DSL to describe the format and then write generic code in the base class that will take care of serializing/deserializing using that recipe:

```
class CTransaction(object):
    format = [('nVersion',  'i'),
              ('vin',       'v', CTxIn),
              ('vout',      'v', CTxOut),
              ('nLockTime', 'I')]

    def __init__(self):
        ... your usual code ...

    def deserialize(self, f):
        for field in self.__class__.format:
            setattr(self, field[0],
                    deserializers[field[1]](f, *field[1:]))
        self.sha256 = None

    def serialize(self):
        res = ""
        for field in self.__class__.format:
            res += serializers[field[1]](getattr(self, field[0]),
                                         *field[1:])
        return res
```

With this approach you never reimplement `serialize`/`deserialize` and for example the `CPosTransaction` class is implemented as

```
class CPosTransaction(CTransaction):
    format = [('nVersion',  'i'),
              ('nTime',     'I'),
              ('vin',       'v', CTxIn),
              ('vout',      'v', CTxOut),
              ('nLockTime', 'I')]

    def __init__(self, ntime):
        ...
```

and `CPosTransactionMessage` is implemented as

```
class CPosTransactionMessage(CTransaction):
    format = [('nVersion',     'i'),
              ('nTime',        'I'),
              ('vin',          'v', CTxIn),
              ('vout',         'v', CTxOut),
              ('nLockTime',    'I'),
              ('strTxComment', 's')]

    def __init__(self, Tx_Message, ntime):
        ...
```

You can even build the recipes at import time if DRY is very important

```
class CPosTransaction(CTransaction):
    # Insert nTime after first field
    format = (CTransaction.format[:1] +
              [('nTime',     'I')] +
              CTransaction.format[1:])

    def __init__(self, ntime):
        ...

class CPosTransactionMessage(CPosTransaction):
    # Append strTxComment at the end
    format = (CPosTransaction.format +
              [('strTxComment', 's')])

    def __init__(self, Tx_Message, ntime):
        ...
```

But of course this would make it harder to understand the code when reading it.